# Regex replace filename in path

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace the "file.type" ending of a path, I have written this regex but it does not seems to work:

```
String path = otherPath.replaceAll("(.*)/[a-zA-Z]*/.[a-zA-Z]*", "")
```

Where is the error?

Example: If I have the path this/is/a/path/file.txt, then I would like to use the statement above to produce the path: this/is/a/path/

Comment: please post input and expected output as well

Comment: *replace the file.type ending*.  You mean the file extension, e.g. ".txt" or ".pdf" ?

Comment: in your above example you are using a variable that is declared on this line...so you are basically searching a null variable and trying to replace it...I know you just made this and likely this isn't the issue but it isn't clear.

Comment: Did some edits to clear things out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = path.replaceAll("(/.)*[a-zA-Z]*", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern may work for you:

```
"[^.\\/]+?\\.[^.]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use: `"\\.+\\w+"` as the regex:

```
String s = "file.type.type.type";

s = s.replaceAll("\\.+\\w+", "");
System.out.println(s); // print "file"
```

here `\\w+` is a [predefined character clas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)s of regular expression which represents, `A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]`

This will output `"file"` removing all the `".type"` at once. However, if you wish to remove only the last `".type"` from the file name, then simplest would be to use `s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."))`, which will remove only the last ".type" from the filename:

```
String s = "file.type.type.type";
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(".")); // print "file.type.type"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

According to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)'s library to parse an extension is the following Regex:

```
\.[^.\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sy6sQ3fk4K1B7Oef)

### Code for you

```
path = path.replaceAll("(?i)\\.[^.\\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+$", "");
```